# converting into integer in excel using EPPlus (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, epplus

I am loading data into excel from datatable using `LoadFromDataTable` method then changed cell format to integer still it is showing error **"The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by apostrophe"**.

cell was showing to right side only and number format only on cell property.

still I am not understanding why I am getting this error??.

```
Dim wsManufacturing As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Manufacturing")
wsManufacturing.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManufacturing, True)
 Using col As ExcelRange = wsManufacturing.Cells(2, 2, 2 + dtManufacturing.Rows.Count, 2)
    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0"
    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right
 End Using
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
//strValue="98.5%";
double realValue=double.Parse(strValue.Replace("%", string.Empty));
Worksheet.Cells[row + 1, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0\\.00%";
Worksheet.Cells[row + 1, col].Value = realValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the format from Text to Number does not change the nature of the entry that was in the cell prior to the format change.

To change entries that were originally textual representations of numbers

1. Change the cell format to Number
2. Enter a 1 in some cell
3. Edit/Copy
4. Select your cell(s) with the text numbers
5. Paste Special / Multiply
6. Delete the original 1